# cakephp 3 translation issue

Tags: flash, localization, cakephp-3.x

***Definition  :***

I want to translate my website  english- arabic . I followed exactly the CakePHP 3 documentation but it is not working.

***What I DO Until now  :***

all content of my website can be translated except flash messages ex: all files.ctp translated normally

***/src/Controller/UsersController :***

```
$this->Flash->error(__('Your username or password is incorrect.'));
```

> No translation appear when i change the language

***.po file generation :***

```
...

msgid "Your username or password is incorrect."

msgstr "اسم المستخدم او كلمة السر غير صحيحتان"

...
```

***Locales directory structure***

The /src/Locale file looks like this now:

```
/ar_JO
   /default.po
```

Despite my attempts to translate my FLASHES messages in my website ,
 I didn't get anything working. I supposed it was a Cache problem, so I deleted the files in /tmp/cache/persistent/.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem  thank you all

i just added  the below code in the controller :

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
.....
....
 $session = $this->request->session();
 $lang=$session->read(’System.language.code’);
        if($lang=='en_US'){
            \Cake\I18n\I18n::locale('en_US');
        }else{
            \Cake\I18n\I18n::locale('ar_JO');
        }
    }
```